# Random freezes on Linux Mint 15 KDE under an UEFI Asus motherboard

Tags: linux, bios, linux-mint

I'm running Linux Mint 15 with KDE, fully updated.

For some reason, I'm experiencing seemly random lock ups.
The GUI doesn't respond to input from mouse & keyboard, plus the interface doesn't update (the clock doesn't move forward, for example).

How can I troubleshoot what the issue is?
I was running Windows 8 completely stable, so I doubt it's hardware related. The CPU temperature is good. So I'm totally at lost for troubleshooting Linux.
I haven't installed anything strange and the lock ups started with a fresh installation.

I've read that Linux has compatibility issues with UEFI. My motherboard, an Asus M5A99X EVO R2.0 only supports UEFI BIOS (can't be disabled). Currently, the legacy mode is activated for boot devices, but I'm not sure what this affects and if it should completely eliminate the incompatibilities between Linux Mint & my UEFI motherboard that might or might not be causing these freezes.

I'm completely lost with this, any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you solve it? I have the same issue for the most current Linux (multiple distros).

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the Wifi card.

It works for [him](http://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=144174.0), it works for [me](https://forum.manjaro.org/index.php?topic=27480.0). Don't ask me why.